# Perl simple xml question

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to parse a simple XML file that I created... it looks like this:

```
<project name="AU" date="2/2/2011" location="proj1">
  <GenomeList name="Processed">
    <genome name="AU4" />
  </GenomeList>
  <GenomeList name="Unprocessed">
      <genome name="AU1" />
      <genome name="AU2" />
      <genome name="AU3" />
  </GenomeList>
</project>
```

The problem I am having is the parsing of the genome list:  It seems that when there is only one element in the list it adds the entry in a different way, as can be seen here:

```
'Unprocessed' => {
                  'genome' => {
                              'AU2' => {},
                              'AU3' => {},
                              'AU1' => {}
                              }
                 },
'Processed' => {
                'genome' => {
                            'name' => 'AU4'
                            }
               }
```

Is there any way I can get it to parse in a consistent way?

I tried using valueAttr but it didnt seem to be working

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for whoever edited this, I was having trouble with it

Comment: Hard to tell why it's not working without seeing the relevant piece of the code.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty common issue with using [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) so I’m guessing this is what you’re using. `ForceArray` will probably do what you want. See the examples and output below; the third print statement should do what you want. Note that XML::Simple is decidedly not simple once your usage expands beyond trivial and predictable in/out stuff. If you want to use it, don’t stop reading its documentation at the word “Simple.”

[XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML) or perhaps [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig) are also well worth learning.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

my $multi = <<"";
<project name="AU" date="2/2/2011" location="proj1">
  <GenomeList name="Processed">
    <genome name="AU4" />
  </GenomeList>
  <GenomeList name="Unprocessed">
      <genome name="AU1" />
      <genome name="AU2" />
      <genome name="AU3" />
  </GenomeList>
</project>

my $single = <<"";
<project name="AU" date="2/2/2011" location="proj1">
  <GenomeList name="Processed">
    <genome name="AU4" />
  </GenomeList>
  <GenomeList name="Unprocessed">
      <genome name="AU1" />
  </GenomeList>
</project>

print Dumper( XMLin($multi) );
print Dumper( XMLin($single) );
print Dumper( XMLin( $single, ForceArray => 1 ) );
```